# How do I convert data from integer and dbl to numeric in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, numeric

As stated above, I'm trying to convert data in my dataframe from integer/dbl to numeric but I end up with dbl for both columns.

[Original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mmnW.png)

Code I'm using to convert to numeric;

```html
data$price <- as.numeric(data$price)
data$lot_size <- as.numeric(data$lot_size)
```

The dataframe I end up with:
[The dataframe I end up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps8s0.png)

Dataset I have been working with: https://dasl.datadescription.com/datafile/housing-prices-ge19

Comment: R has the following numeric types: integer, double, complex. Numeric and double are the same. There is no such thing as conversion from double to numeric. Fun history fact, double used to be called real until R 3.0.0, which is why the NA of double type is still `NA_real_`.

Comment: Your statement may be a bit confusing. Yes, complex is a 'numeric data type' in the sense that it stores numbers and we can calculate with it. However, R does not consider objects of type 'complex' to be also of type 'numeric': `is.numeric(complex(real = 1, imaginary = 0))` evaluates to `FALSE`.
'numeric' is superclass of both 'double' and 'integer': `getClass("numeric")`

Answer (score 1):

"numeric is identical to double"
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/numeric.html

```
> typeof(as.numeric(3L))
[1] "double"
> typeof(as.integer(3L))
[1] "integer"
```

Answer (score 1):

The stuff with types in R is a bit confusing. I would say that `numeric` is not really a data type at all in R. You will never get the answer numeric from the `typeof` function.

Both, integers and doubles are considered to be numeric and the function `is.numeric` will return TRUE for either.

On the other hand, numeric is more often a synonym for double.
The functions `numeric` and `as.numeric` are the same as `double` and `as.double`.

Edit:
With a bit more research under my belt let me rephrase it like this:
'numeric' is the ***virtual** superclass* of both integer and double.
See for example `getClass("numeric")` and `help(UseMethod)` (first paragraph in the Details section).

Hadley says it better: [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/base-types.html#numeric-type)

Comment: isn't the missing link, that there is a class "numeric" and a class "integer". I remember vaguely that these are somehow connected to the types (obtained with typeof) double and integer..

Comment: I think the missing link is that 'numeric' is the virtual superclass of both double and integer. The difficulty arises largely from the fact that there are the functions `numeric / as.numeric`, which are identical to the corresponding `double` functions.